# FORFILES with spaces in the path

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run this command in dos

```
FORFILES with params /P C:\Builds\ /M *.chm /S /C "cmd /c copy @file C:\My Brand\"
```

It bombs because there is a space in the destination folder path. How can I pass the source and destination path delimited by ""? I tried by adding an additional double quote and I get "command not recognized"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0x22` is a representation of a double quote (hex encoded).

```
FORFILES /P C:\Builds\ /M *.chm /S /C "cmd /c copy @file 0x22C:\My Brand\0x22"
```

Answer (score 5):

Escape the quotes surrounding the destination path with a backslash:

```
FORFILES /P C:\Builds\ /M *.chm /S /C "cmd /c copy @file \"C:\My Brand\\""
```